# What kind of lock does INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE obtain when the UPDATE is a no-op?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.7

I am working on an apparent performance problem possibly involving row lock contention, and I'm seeking to understand whether `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Foo=Foo` (with a no-op in the UPDATE clause) obtains the same kind of lock as it would if the UPDATE clause were not a no-op, or if MySQL can recognize the no-op and obtain a less-expensive lock. Googling for the relevant documentation has thus far failed to provide an answer either way.

Comment: If you need in no-op UPDATE clause then use not `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` but `INSERT IGNORE`.

Comment: Need some context -- What else is going on?  Let's see the query _and_ `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  How many rows are being inserted at once?

Comment: And,...  If your version handles such, provide `EXPLAIN INSERT ...`

Comment: This is a single row insert that should hit the table's unique key. There is no WHERE.

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+-----------------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys         | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+-----------------------+------+---------+------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | INSERT      | my_table | NULL       | ALL  | my_unique_key | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL |     NULL | NULL
```